# A diophantine equation involving partial sums of exponentials similar than the equation in Fermat's Last Theorem

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations, factorization, divisors-multiples

I'm curious about the following diophantine equation from my invention: I don't know if this is in the literature, I wrote it using creativity in an attempt to write a variant of the equation in Fermat's Last Theorem.

**Problem.** *We consider for positive integers* $x,y,z\geq 1$ *and being pairwise coprime*, $(x,y)=(x,z)=(y,z)=1$, *and for a fixed integer* $n\geq 3$ *the diophantine equation that involves partial sums of exponentials* $$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^k}{k!}+\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{y^k}{k!}=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{z^k}{k!}.\tag{1}$$
*The problem asks if it is possible to determine if $(1)$ for our given integer $n>2$ has solutions.*

> **Question.** I don't know if previous problem is in the literature. Is it possible to determine for a given integer $n\geq 3$ if the diophantine equation (the problem) have solutions $(x,y,z)$ in coprime positive integers $x,y,z$? **Many thanks.**

If this problem is in the literature please refer it in your comments of answer.

**Example (Case $n=2$).** One can to get easily solutions for the equation with $n=2$ that isn't considered in our **Problem**. For example  $(x,y,z)=(17,5,18)$.

**Remark.** I know that the polynomial $P(x)=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\ldots+\frac{x^n}{n!}$ is in the literature and enjoys of certain properties.

Comment: For $n=4$, you have the solution $(x,y,z) = (32, 51, 53)$.

Comment: Many thanks, this is excellent @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda , I hope that if it is feasible you or other professor can to add a discussion, this is the purpose of the question, **about what work can be done for the Question.**